# opencv python :why do it like this

Tags: python, opencv, video

i dont know why in video stabilization the image or the frame is being converted to gray scale and then stabilized and again back to it?

I tried to do it in  the normal rgb format but nothing is changing

```py
# Convert frame to grayscale
prev_gray = cv2.cvtColor(prev, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you're asking. `back to it` - back to what? What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: @RadhikaS could you please provide more context, maybe the `while` block where you process the images ? Also, have a look at [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) when you get a chance and earn a badge :)